# Meteor - Wrapping NPMs with Meteor.wrapAsync()

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm trying to wrap the superagent NPM with Meteor.wrapAsync, everything works fine until the last line of the code below, which causes my meteor app to crash.

```
var superagent = Meteor.npmRequire('superagent');

// Example of how superagent works
superagent.get('http://127.0.0.1:8080/json/', function(result){
    console.log(result); // Works, shows the result
});

// This appears to work too
var agentAsync = Meteor.wrapAsync(superagent.get);

// This crashes app
agentAsync('http://127.0.0.1:8080/json/');
```

I've also tried passing a context to wrapAsync() and it makes no difference:

```
var agentAsync = Meteor.wrapAsync(superagent.get, superagent);
```

Here is the console output:

```
W20141124-17:31:32.094(0)? (STDERR)           
W20141124-17:31:32.136(0)? (STDERR) /home/ciwolsey/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.1bjny7b++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:206
W20141124-17:31:32.136(0)? (STDERR)                         throw(ex);
W20141124-17:31:32.137(0)? (STDERR)                               ^
W20141124-17:31:32.137(0)? (STDERR) [object Object]
W20141124-17:31:32.137(0)? (STDERR)     at Object.Future.wait (/home/ciwolsey/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.1bjny7b++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:326:15)
W20141124-17:31:32.137(0)? (STDERR)     at packages/meteor/helpers.js:118
W20141124-17:31:32.137(0)? (STDERR)     at app/server/main.js:5:1
W20141124-17:31:32.137(0)? (STDERR)     at app/server/main.js:8:3
W20141124-17:31:32.137(0)? (STDERR)     at /home/ciwolsey/projects/hello/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:168:10
W20141124-17:31:32.138(0)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20141124-17:31:32.138(0)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/home/ciwolsey/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.35.1bjny7b++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W20141124-17:31:32.138(0)? (STDERR)     at /home/ciwolsey/projects/hello/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:82:5
=> Exited with code: 8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the source to [`Meteor.wrapAsync`](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/50e6d3143db8fc6e1fc3fb74da74b40c8dc7f3a4/packages/meteor/helpers.js#L90) and the source to [`superget.get`](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent/blob/b36fd692139cf366486d45783ede45a4c90c4764/lib/client.js#L982)

`Meteor.wrapAsync` is basically a thin wrapper around [`Meteor.bindEnviroment`](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/556c0e28e94b9351cbf0b28e80a71a4e35f1362a/packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js#L84). It provides a bound function which waits on a `Fiber`.

`superget.get` eventually tries to call the callback function passed to it with [`Request.prototype.callback`](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent/blob/b36fd692139cf366486d45783ede45a4c90c4764/lib/client.js#L814)

What's interesting here is that `Meteor.bindEnvironment` takes the [`Fibers.resolver`](https://github.com/laverdet/node-fibers/blob/master/future.js#L309) function (which takes **two arguments**), and wraps it in a function that takes **no arguments**.

So when `Request.prototype.callback` tries to look at `fn.length` to see if it should call it with `(err, res)` or send the error off with `emit`... it does the latter..

To make this work, we need to short-circuit `Request.prototype.callback` and make it think that functions with no arguments are fine to call as `fn(err, res)`

```
superget.Request.prototype.callback = function(err, res){
  var fn = this._callback;
  if (2 == fn.length || 0 == fn.length) return fn(err, res);
  if (err) return this.emit('error', err);
  fn(res);
};
```

Alternatively, you could write your own `Meteor.wrapAsync` that provides a callback with the right function length. eg:

```
function wrapAsync(fn, context) {
  //XXX Shortened version of wrapAsync. Only works on server, doesn't allow for callback to be passed.
  return function (/* arguments */) {
    var self = context || this;
    var newArgs = _.toArray(arguments);
    var fut = new Future();
    var callback = Meteor.bindEnvironment(fut.resolver());
    newArgs.push(function(err, res){
      return callback.apply(this, arguments);
    });
    fn.apply(self, newArgs);
    return fut.wait()
  };
}
```

Comment: Opened an issue on the meteor github regarding this https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/3176

Comment: Great explanation, thank you for making such an effort, and for submitting it as an issue ;)

Answer (score 0):

`Meteor.wrapAsync` takes a second argument which is the context the wrapped function should be called with (to preserve `this` correct value).

Try using this syntax instead :

```
var agentAsync = Meteor.wrapAsync(superagent.get, superagent);
```

If you don't pass the correct context, the call will crash your app because it won't be able to fetch `this` properties as it should normally do when you call `superagent.get` directly.

Comment: I've already tried that, and just tried it again. I'm still getting crashes.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Future?
Here's an example

```
Meteor.methods({
  syncMethod: function() {
    // load Future
    Future = Npm.require('fibers/future');
    var theFuture = new Future();

    // call the function and store its result
    TheAsyncFuncWeWantItToWait("foo", function (error,results){
      if(error){
        theFuture.throw(error);
      }else{
        theFuture.return(results);
      }
    });

    return theFuture.wait();
  }
});
```

Comment: I assume this will work as it worked when I did it manually with fibers but I'm just curious why none of the meteor wrapping methods work.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I didn't see a clear answer here so I wanted to share what worked for me.

```
const request = superagent
  .post(`${basePath}/api/xxx`)
  .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
  .send({ fileReference });
const response = Meteor.wrapAsync(request.end, request)();
```

Since `request.end()` is the function that expects a callback, this is what you want to pass into Meteor.wrapAsync. And you have to bind the callback to the original request, otherwise it runs in the global context (but it needs to run in the context of the original request).

Hopefully this helps someone else!